# Emacs: how to make it an editor in a midnight-commander?

Tags: emacs, mc

My question is about Midnight-commander. I've unset usage of internal editor (in Options -> Configuration) and put in `.bashrc`:

```
export EDITOR='emacsclient -n'
```

still - pressing F4 gives nothing, pressing F3 - opens in `vi`. Is there a way to make `emacsclient` to be a default text editor in `mc`?

Comment: Works fine for me if I do `export EDITOR=pico`. Try running the `export`-command manually first, it could be that you put it in .bashrc without re-reading it (with `. ~/.bashrc`).

Comment: Setting the `EDITOR` variable does work. What @bos said, did you actually set the variable by exporting it in the current process or by sourcing `.bashrc`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove ~/.selected_editor, then when you press F4 next time, MC will prompt for select editor. Or, you may directly change it.

```
$ cat .selected_editor
# Generated by /usr/bin/select-editor
SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/vim.basic"
```

This works on Ubuntu. I have tried any other ways to setup default editor which won't help.

Comment: Editing the file directly has some advantages, since the mc uses the full path to the editor, so if you share the `.selected_editor` file across multiple computers (e.g. at work or school), it may not work. If you try `SELECTED_EDITOR="/usr/bin/env emacs"`, then it should work anywhere the `emacs` command works.

Answer (score 4):

Run MC as usual. On the command line right above the bottom row of menu selections type "select-editor" without the quotes. This should open a menu with a list of all of your installed editors. This is working for me on all my current linux machines.

Answer (score 3):

What I do is change the **~/.mc/bindings** file:

```
### Default ###

# Default target for anything not described above
default/*
    Open=%var{EDITOR:emacs} %f &
    View=
```

That way I can still view files with F3, but F4 or enter usually edits them with Emacs.

By the way, the ampersand is so that the file will pop up in X, and I can continue in mc. You may have to remove that if you're only working on the command line.

**UPDATE:** If you don't have a `~/.mc/bindings` file, from inside mc, press **F9 c e** (Menu, Commands, Edit extension file), and it should get you there.

In addition, you need to switch off the internal edit option by going to **F9 o c t** (Menu, Options, Configuration, use Internal edit), unchecking the box, and then saving the options.

Comment: I don't have `bindings` file at all. Can You upload it here?

Comment: From inside mc, **F9 c e** (Menu, Commands, Edit extension file) should get you there. My own `bindings` file will probably not work for you.

Comment: I did as You told me. `bindings` file appeared in `~./mc`. Unbelievably but it doesn't work for me - `emacs` nor `emacsclient` nor `'emacsclient -n'`.

Comment: See the answer above - you need to disable the internal editor too.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution: edit the extension-file and **add** an Edit-entry.
*(Sorry, not enough reputation to add this as comment to Gustav Bertram's answer.)*

Be sure to use MidnightCommander's built-in functionality, as the location of config-files seems to change between some versions of MC.

So press `F9` or `ESC,9` (to open the menu), then go to `Command -> Edit Extension File`.
In the editor, find the last block looking like that:

```
# Default target for anything not described above
default /*
            Open=
            View=
```

Change it to something like that (note the added `Edit`-line!!!):

```
# Default target for anything not described above
default/*
        Open= %var{EDITOR:emacs} %f &
        View=
        Edit= %var{EDITOR:emacs} %f &
```

After saving the file, be sure to turn the internal editor **off**!!
(`F9` or `ESC,9`, `Options -> Configuration`, "`Use internal edit`" must be unchecked)

That way (working at least with later versions of MC) you can have three different editors (or command-line options) to open a file: "View" (`F3`), "Edit" (`F4`) and "Open" (`Enter`) - each individually configurable.

**Note #1**: If you added a custom `view`-command, do not forget to uncheck "`Use internal view`" under `Options -> Configuration`.
**Note #2**: MC still uses its preferred editor (e.g. nano) for editing config-files when opening them from within MC.

Answer (score 2):

I found a way: one can use mc's macro feature. For that make a file:

```
e   Open in emacsclient
    emacsclient -n %s
```

and save it as `~/.mc/menu` or `~/.mc.menu`. After that on pressin `F2` - You'll get a list of Your's functions. And there will be a function `Open in emacs` - which will be accessible by the `e`. So the two keys `F2-e` open current file (or all selected files) in `emacsclient -n`.

Comment: I really don't think Your way was impossible. I must be doing smth in a wrong way.